# Changing Wordpress locale as set by yoast SEO plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My WordPress site is based in Great Britain. I was able to change the html `lang`-attribute from `en-US` to `en-GB`, however when I view my source code the `og:locale` attribute of open graph displays as `en-US`, it is generated by yoast SEO plugin. Is there a way to change locale to `en-GB`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-api-docs/):

> `wpseo_locale (string)`
>
> Allows changing the locale used in the opengraph set (and possibly in other locations later on).

Here's [a specific example](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-how-do-you-set-the-oglocale-value) of how someone else solved it in functions.php:

```
add_filter('wpseo_locale', 'override_og_locale');
function override_og_locale($locale)
{
    return "en_GB";
}
```

Comment: Time has passed but this is now changed to the lang in yoast too. No need for the code in functions anymore.